# Overload operator< for an array of long values

Tags: c++

My implementation of the operator< overload does not work properly for my wrapper class around an array of long values.

While using this wrapper class for a Key inside a std::map, calling functions at/find does not work if I mix arrays of different length.

```
const oid oid1[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,42570,1,3,1 };
oid_wrapper wrapper1(oid1, 10);
const oid oid2[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,42570,1,3,1,9,1 };
oid_wrapper wrapper1(oid2, 12);
```

When adding wrapper1 first and then wrapper2 to the map, it will always find wrapper1 with at/find, but for wrapper2 it throws an out_of_range exception with at and iterator.end with find. 

When adding wrapper2 first and then wrapper1 to the map, it will always find wrapper2 with at/find, but for wrapper1 it throws an out_of_range exception with at and iterator.end with find.

The type oid is from Net-SNMP and is actually an unsigned long int.
So what is my implementation missing or doing completely wrong?

```
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h>
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-includes.h>

class oid_wrapper {
public:
    oid_wrapper(const oid* _oid_value, int _oid_length) : oid_value(0), oid_length  (_oid_length) {
        oid_value = snmp_duplicate_objid(_oid_value, oid_length);
    }

    const oid* get_oid() const { return oid_value; }
    const int& get_length() const { return oid_length; }

    /**
     * copy operator overloader
     */
    oid_wrapper& operator=(const oid_wrapper& wrapper) {
        oid_value = snmp_duplicate_objid(wrapper.get_oid(), wrapper.get_length());
        oid_length = wrapper.get_length();

        return *this;
    }

    /**
     * equal operator overloader
     */
    bool operator==(const oid_wrapper& rhs) const {
        const oid* rhs_oid = rhs.get_oid();
        const int rhs_length = rhs.get_length();

        if (netsnmp_oid_equals(oid_value, oid_length, rhs_oid, rhs_length) == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * less-than operator overloader
     */
    bool operator<(const oid_wrapper& rhs) const {
        const oid* rhs_oid = rhs.get_oid();
        const int rhs_length = rhs.get_length();

        if (oid_length < rhs_length) { return true; }

        for (int i = 0; i < oid_length; i++) {
            if (oid_value[i] < rhs_oid[i]) { return true; }
        }

        return false;
    }

    const long getLastNumberInOid() const { return oid_value[oid_length - 1]; }

    bool operator!=(const oid_wrapper& rhs) { return !operator==(rhs); }
    bool operator>(const oid_wrapper& rhs) { return !operator<(rhs); }
    bool operator<=(const oid_wrapper& rhs) { return !operator>(rhs); }
    bool operator>=(const oid_wrapper& rhs) { return !operator<(rhs); }

private:
    const oid* oid_value;
    int oid_length;
};
```

This i my testclass I designed to check if it worked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h>
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-includes.h>

#include "oid_wrapper.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    cout << "Testing first set of OID" << endl;
    const oid oid1[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,40850,1,3 };
    const oid_wrapper parent1 (oid1, 9);
    const oid_wrapper parent1_child1 (parent1, 40);
    const oid_wrapper parent1_child2 (parent1, 41);
    const oid_wrapper parent1_child3 (parent1, 42);
    const oid_wrapper parent1_child4 (parent1, 43);

    map<oid_wrapper, string> test;
    test.insert(make_pair(parent1_child1, "parent1_child1"));
    test.insert(make_pair(parent1_child2, "parent1_child2"));
    test.insert(make_pair(parent1_child3, "parent1_child3"));
    test.insert(make_pair(parent1_child4, "parent1_child4"));
    if (test.size() != 4) { cout << "FAIL" << endl; }
    cout << "Number of OID in list: " << test.size() << endl;

    const oid_wrapper parent11 (oid1, 9);
    const oid_wrapper parent1_child11 (parent11, 40);
    try {
        string teststring = test.at(parent1_child11);
        cout << "Success" << endl;
    } catch (out_of_range& e) {
        cout << "Failure" << endl;
    }

    const oid_wrapper parent1_child12 (parent11, 41);
    try {
        string teststring = test.at(parent1_child12);
        cout << "Success" << endl;
    } catch (out_of_range& e) {
        cout << "Failure" << endl;
    }

    const oid_wrapper parent1_child13 (parent11, 42);
    try {
        string teststring = test.at(parent1_child13);
        cout << "Success" << endl;
    } catch (out_of_range& e) {
        cout << "Failure" << endl;
    }

    const oid_wrapper parent1_child14 (parent11, 43);
    try {
        string teststring = test.at(parent1_child14);
        cout << "Success" << endl;
    } catch (out_of_range& e) {
        cout << "Failure" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Testing second set of OID" << endl;
    const oid oid2[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,40850,2,1,9,1 };
    const oid_wrapper parent2 (oid2, 11);
    const oid_wrapper parent2_child1 (parent2, 1);
    const oid_wrapper parent2_child2 (parent2, 2);
    const oid_wrapper parent2_child3 (parent2, 3);
    const oid_wrapper parent2_child4 (parent2, 4);

    test.insert(make_pair(parent2_child1, "parent2_child1"));
    test.insert(make_pair(parent2_child2, "parent2_child2"));
    test.insert(make_pair(parent2_child3, "parent2_child3"));
    test.insert(make_pair(parent2_child4, "parent2_child4"));
    if (test.size() != 8) { cout << "FAIL" << endl; }
    cout << "Number of OID in list: " << test.size() << endl;

    const oid_wrapper parent21 (oid2, 11);
    const oid_wrapper parent1_child21 (parent21, 1);
    try {
        string teststring = test.at(parent1_child21);
        cout << "Success" << endl;
    } catch (out_of_range& e) {
        cout << "Failure" << endl;
    }

    const oid_wrapper parent1_child22 (parent21, 2);
    try {
        string teststring = test.at(parent1_child22);
        cout << "Success" << endl;
    } catch (out_of_range& e) {
        cout << "Failure" << endl;
    }

    const oid_wrapper parent1_child23 (parent21, 3);
    try {
        string teststring = test.at(parent1_child23);
        cout << "Success" << endl;
    } catch (out_of_range& e) {
        cout << "Failure" << endl;
    }

    const oid_wrapper parent1_child24 (parent21, 4);
    try {
        string teststring = test.at(parent1_child24);
        cout << "Success" << endl;
    } catch (out_of_range& e) {
        cout << "Failure" << endl;
    }

    //#################################################

    //Adding 100 OIDs
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const oid newoid[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,40850,2,1,9,1 };
        const oid_wrapper wrapper(newoid, 11, i);
        test.insert(make_pair(wrapper, "wrapper"));
    }

    //Query for the 100 added OIDs
    int run1 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const oid newoid[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,40850,2,1,9,1 };
        const oid_wrapper wrapper(newoid, 11, i);

        try {
            string teststring = test.at(wrapper);
            run1++;
        } catch (out_of_range& e) {
            //FAIL
        }
    }
    if (run1 == 100) { cout << "Run 1 Success" << endl; }
    else { cout << "Run 1: " << run1 << endl; }

    //#################################################

    //Adding 100 OIDs
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const oid newoid[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,40850,1,3 };
        const oid_wrapper wrapper(newoid, 9, i);
        test.insert(make_pair(wrapper, "wrapper"));
    }

    //Query for the 100 added OIDs
    int run2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const oid newoid[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,40850,1,3 };
        const oid_wrapper wrapper(newoid, 9, i);

        try {
            string teststring = test.at(wrapper);
            run2++;
        } catch (out_of_range& e) {
            //FAIL
        }
    }
    if (run2 == 100) { cout << "Run 2 Success" << endl; }
    else { cout << "Run 2: " << run2 << endl; }

    //#################################################

    //Adding 100 OIDs
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const oid newoid[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,40850,2 };
        const oid_wrapper wrapper(newoid, 8, i);
        test.insert(make_pair(wrapper, "wrapper"));
    }

    //Query for the 100 added OIDs
    int run3 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const oid newoid[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,40850,2 };
        const oid_wrapper wrapper(newoid, 8, i);

        try {
            string teststring = test.at(wrapper);
            run3++;
        } catch (out_of_range& e) {
            //FAIL
        }
    }
    if (run3 == 10) { cout << "Run 3 Success" << endl; }
    else { cout << "Run 3: " << run3 << endl; }

    //#################################################

    //Adding 100 OIDs
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const oid newoid[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,40850,2,2,5,1 };
        const oid_wrapper wrapper(newoid, 11, i);
        test.insert(make_pair(wrapper, "wrapper"));
    }

    //Query for the 100 added OIDs
    int run4 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const oid newoid[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,40850,2,2,5,1 };
        const oid_wrapper wrapper(newoid, 11, i);

        try {
            string teststring = test.at(wrapper);
            run4++;
        } catch (out_of_range& e) {
            //FAIL
        }
    }
    if (run4 == 100) { cout << "Run 4 Success" << endl; }
    else { cout << "Run 4: " << run4 << endl; }

    //#################################################

    //Adding 100 OIDs
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const oid newoid[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,40850,2,3,5,2 };
        const oid_wrapper wrapper(newoid, 11, i);
        test.insert(make_pair(wrapper, "wrapper"));
    }

    //Query for the 100 added OIDs
    int run5 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const oid newoid[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,40850,2,3,5,2 };
        const oid_wrapper wrapper(newoid, 11, i);

        try {
            string teststring = test.at(wrapper);
            run5++;
        } catch (out_of_range& e) {
            //FAIL
        }
    }
    if (run5 == 100) { cout << "Run 5 Success" << endl; }
    else { cout << "Run 5: " << run5 << endl; }

    //#################################################

    //Adding 100 OIDs
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const oid newoid[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,40850,2,2,5,2 };
        const oid_wrapper wrapper(newoid, 10, i);
        test.insert(make_pair(wrapper, "wrapper"));
    }

    //Query for the 100 added OIDs
    int run6 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const oid newoid[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,40850,2,2,5,2 };
        const oid_wrapper wrapper(newoid, 10, i);

        try {
            string teststring = test.at(wrapper);
            run6++;
        } catch (out_of_range& e) {
            //FAIL
        }
    }
    if (run6 == 100) { cout << "Run 6 Success" << endl; }
    else { cout << "Run 6: " << run6 << endl; }

    //#################################################

    //Adding 100 OIDs
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const oid newoid[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,40850,2,5,2,3,5 };
        const oid_wrapper wrapper(newoid, 12, i);
        test.insert(make_pair(wrapper, "wrapper"));
    }

    //Query for the 100 added OIDs
    int run7 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        const oid newoid[] = { 1,3,6,1,4,1,40850,2,5,2,3,5 };
        const oid_wrapper wrapper(newoid, 12, i);

        try {
            string teststring = test.at(wrapper);
            run7++;
        } catch (out_of_range& e) {
            //FAIL
        }
    }
    if (run7 == 100) { cout << "Run 7 Success" << endl; }
    else { cout << "Run 7: " << run7 << endl; }
}
```

Comment: I can't answer your main question, but your code does have some different problems:
op> is not equal to !op<. As you may notice, your definition of op>= and op> are the same, while they shouldn't be. This can lead to inconsistencies if any built-in function requires comparisons.

Comment: Btw, with the right template constructor, you can avoid having to pass the array size alongside (`template <size_t N> oid_wrapper(const oid (&array)[N]) : oid_value(array /* or whatever */), oid_length(N) {}`; now you can just do `oid_wrapper wrapper(oid1);` and get the size for free)

Comment: Fernandes: Nice, but that works only if I have the array itself. With oid[] oid1. However with Net-SNMP it mostly works with pointers, so I have the pointer and the length.

Gaminic: The std::map::at or std::map::find uses only the operator<, so even if the other are somewhat wrong it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I think you're missing an `if (oid_length > rhs_length) { return false; }`, not sure if it causes your error though.

Comment: Rau: I added what you suggested. It solved the problem.

Comment: Tip: Write a `compare()` function that returns `-1, 0 or -1`. Implement all the operators in terms of this function.

Comment: @DJViking Ah, too bad I didn't make it an answer, but you can just [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/162011) *Angew*'s answer, which says the same with a thorough explanation.

Comment: Take a look at `lexicographical_compare` (and use it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be that your `operator<` is not antisymmetrical. Imagine this code:

```
const oid oid1[] = {5};
oid_wrapper wrapper1(oid1, 1);

const oid oid2[] = {1, 4};
oid_wrapper wrapper2(oid2, 2);

bool b1 = wrapper1 < wrapper2;
bool b2 = wrapper2 < wrapper1;
```

`b1` is `true`, because the legth of `wrapper1` is less than length of `wrapper2`.

`b2` is also `true`, because the first oid in `wrapper2` is less than that in `wrapper1`.

You must make sure `operator<` is a total ordering. It should return `false` if `oid_length > rhs_length`.

Also, you cannot implement `operator>` as `! <`, because that doesn't hold for equal values. The best bet for operators is to implement `operator==` and `operator<` and express the rest as (pseudo-code):

```
operator!=(a, b)  {! (a == b)}
operator<=(a, b)  {a < b || a == b}
operator>(a, b)   {! (a < b)}
operator>=(a, b)  {! (a < b)}
```

Comment: @DJViking Why the silent unaccept? If the answer doesn't work, say how; I would try to improve it.

Comment: I was composing a reply.. A made a small test where I created multiple oid_wrapper, at some point it could not find all of those I added. Adding my testclass in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I used net-snmp function snmp_oid_compare instead of implementing my own compare. That solved the problem.

```
#ifndef OID_WRAPPER_H_
#define OID_WRAPPER_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h>
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-includes.h>

class oid_wrapper {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const oid_wrapper& wrapper);
public:
    oid_wrapper(const oid* _oid_value, unsigned long _oid_length) : oid_value(0), oid_length(_oid_length) {
        oid_value = snmp_duplicate_objid(_oid_value, oid_length);

    }

    const oid* get_oid() const { return oid_value; }
    const unsigned long& get_length() const { return oid_length; }

    int compare(const oid_wrapper& rhs) const {
        return snmp_oid_compare(oid_value, oid_length, rhs.oid_value, rhs.oid_length);
    }

    void print(std::ostream &out) const {
        for(unsigned long i = 0; i < oid_length; i++) {
            if (i != 0) { out << "."; }
            out << oid_value[i];
        }
    }

    /**
     * copy operator overload
     */
    oid_wrapper& operator=(const oid_wrapper& wrapper) {
        if (oid_value != 0) { free(oid_value); }

        oid_value = snmp_duplicate_objid(wrapper.oid_value, wrapper.oid_length);
        oid_length = wrapper.oid_length;

        return *this;
    }

    /**
     * assignment operator overload
     */
    oid operator[](unsigned long i) {
        return (i < oid_length) ? oid_value[i] : oid();
    }

    bool operator==(const oid_wrapper& rhs) const { return compare(rhs)==0; }
    bool operator!=(const oid_wrapper& rhs) const { return compare(rhs)!=0; }
    bool operator<(const oid_wrapper& rhs) const { return compare(rhs)<0; }
    bool operator>(const oid_wrapper& rhs) const { return compare(rhs)>0; }
    bool operator<=(const oid_wrapper& rhs) const { return compare(rhs)<=0; }
    bool operator>=(const oid_wrapper& rhs) const { return compare(rhs)>=0; }

private:
    oid* oid_value;
    unsigned long oid_length;
};

/**
 * output operator overloader
 */
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const oid_wrapper& wrapper) {
    wrapper.print(output);
    return output;
}

#endif /* OID_WRAPPER_H_ */
```

The code for function snmp_oid_compare. This could be used for any implementation where one would need to compare arrays of long.

```
    int snmp_oid_compare(const oid * in_name1, size_t len1, 
                     const oid * in_name2, size_t len2)
    {
        register int len;
        register const oid *name1 = in_name1;
        register const oid *name2 = in_name2;

        /*
         * len = minimum of len1 and len2
         */
        if (len1 < len2) { len = len1; }
        else { len = len2; }

        /*
         * find first non-matching OID
         */
        while (len-- > 0) {
            /*
             * these must be done in seperate comparisons, since
             * subtracting them and using that result has problems with
             * subids > 2^31.
             */
            if (*(name1) != *(name2)) {
                if (*(name1) < *(name2)) { return -1; }
                return 1;
            }
            name1++;
            name2++;
        }

        /*
         * both OIDs equal up to length of shorter OID
         */
        if (len1 < len2) return -1;
        if (len2 < len1) return 1;

        return 0;
    }
```